# Regarding arm instruction timing

Tags: assembly, arm, timing, neon

On arm website, instruction timing for **Cortex-a9 processor** is provided. 
[Instruction Link](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0409f/ch03s04s01.html)

For each instruction (to be specific, I'm talking about *NEON vector instruction*), the timing is 
given in a table of the format shown below (using VADD instruction as example):

```
NAME    FORMAT    Cycle      Source    Result    Writeback 
VADD    Dd,Dn,Dm  1          -,2,2     3         6
```

I kinda understand what the table is trying to say. For example, the Result with value 3 means 
the result of this instruction will be available at cycle 3, and then other instruction depending
on the result of this instruction can smoothly use the result without stall.

**But My question is:**

When does this cycle number start to count? Does it count after the instruction
is issued?

Also, as I know, issue is a step when the instruction is sent to the processor to execute after 
the instruction is fetched and decoded, then why doesn't the decode and fetch cycles show on the 
table then? It is very important information since I need to know the fetch and decode cycles to 
be able to know how many cycles I have to wait to execute smoothly an instruction which depends on 
the result of the previous instruction.

A clear and precise response or a place to look it up will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you so much ooga, for the modification of my post errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using timing tables on complex pipelined processors like A9 is really hard and ungrateful task. Better use a simulation, since these tables provide absolute theoretical minimum of how long this instruction will take,  it has somewhat low correlation with reality.   Since you need to take into account what's in your caches and other externalities like this.

Anyway,  here is my understanding of this table.   Since Cortex A9 supports out of order execution,  the fetch and decode cycles don't matter.  That's why they count from the issue time.  You can add fetch and decode cycles yourself,  but you have to consider effects of previous instructions and things like memory barriers to count them accurately.

The table above shows that minimum issue time for this instruction will be 1 cycle.  Therefor the source values must be available in the next cycle  (cycle 2) to avoid the stall.   The instruction takes only one cycle to run after the source results showed up, so the very next instruction might use the results, if a forwarding path exist within the CPU.  However it takes another 3 cycles (until cycle six) for the results be committed to the register file where it is guaranteed that any instruction can access the results.

The bottom line is this instruction can take between 1 to 6 cycles to execute under ideal circumstances.  No cache waits, no memory barriers, etc.